# Let $f$ be a Lipschitz function then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|\int_0^1 f - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n f(\frac{i}{n})| < \frac{M}{2n} $

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f$ be a Lipschitz function then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|\int_0^1 f - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n f(\frac{i}{n})| < \frac{M}{2n} $ where $M$ is the Lipschitz constant.

I have proven this result for $\frac{M}{n}$ using the intermediate value theorem for integrals. And using the hint given in [Riemann sum and integral approximation error (Lipschitz function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290062/riemann-sum-and-integral-approximation-error-lipschitz-function) and the ftc I have managed to prove the result for  $\frac{M}{2n}$, but what I don't understand is why
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n f(\frac{i}{n})=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}(f(x)-f(k/n))\,dx$$ is true.

What i've done is this
$$\int_0^1 f  - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n f(\frac{i}{n}) =\sum_{i = 1}^n \int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}} f -  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n f(\frac{i}{n})  $$

I don't see how he got rid of the $\frac{1}{n}$ in the above hint. Could anyone please tell me how?

note: I don't  believe this is a duplicate of [sum approximation of a Lipschitz-continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237798/sum-approximation-of-a-lipschitz-continuous-function) because the question asks for $\frac{M}{n}$, the other question asks  $\frac{M}{2n}$ but it only has the hint and it was posted a long time ago, so I don't think that he will answer if I comment there.

Comment: That’s because $f(i/n)/n=\int_{(i-1)/n}^{i/n}{f(i/n)dx}$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$|\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac kn}(f(x)-f(\frac kn))|\le$$

$$M\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac kn}(\frac kn -x)dx$$